# What does "I have burst out of my shoe!" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> I cannot lend you any of my ships for the venture; Philip would hear
>   of it,' she whispered over her shoulder; 'but as much guns and powder as
>   you ask, if you do not ask too--'Her voice shot up and she stamped her
>   foot thrice. 'Louder! Louder, the music in the gallery! Oh, me, but I
>   have burst out of my shoe!

This is from "Gloriana" in *Reward and Fairies*  by Kipling.

I am glad if some one kindly teach me what "I have burst out of my shoe!" means.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty close, if not exactly right.

> [burst](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/burst)
>   a :  to emerge or spring suddenly

So as you can imagine, after she stomped her foot three times, her foot suddenly sprung out of the shoe. Another way to understand this is that her foot suddenly **slipped** out of her shoe. *Burst* has an "explosive" connotation. So it suggests that her foot **violently** came out of her shoe.